# Adding OpenRouteService to Angular Application on Stackbliz

Tags: javascript, angular, api, npm

I added `OpenRouteService` to my Stackbliz application but cant get it working.
the Component looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {Openrouteservice} from '/openrouteservice-js/dist/ors-js-client';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-event-plan',
 templateUrl: './event-plan.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./event-plan.component.scss']
})

export class EventPlanComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _location: Location) { 
  console.log("++++")
  console.log(Openrouteservice)
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 backClicked() {
  this._location.back();
 }
}
```

**My problem is that it just doesnt get loaded. I added it as a dependency in the dependency section.**

I made the project public here is the url - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-micwge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fevent-plan%2Fevent-plan.component.ts

Comment: You can't get `this._location.back();` to work or you can't get `Openrouteservice` to load? btw your stackblitz doesn't work

Comment: I just can't get Openrouteservice to work. Even the console log throws an error because the import doesnt work.

Comment: The link should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change the way you `import` the library. The current way you `import` is looking for a named export from the library.

If you have `allowSyntheticImports` and `esModuleInterop` in your `tsconfig.json` use this:

```js
import Openrouteservice from 'openrouteservice-js';
```

otherwise:

```js
import * as Openrouteservice from 'openrouteservice-js';
```

Find your [forked stacknlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-adding-openrouteservice-to-angular-application-on-stackbliz)

Comment: Thank you! But it says "Can't find package:openrouteservice-js" (you can see it in my stackbliz). I think the main Problem is, that it cant be found but i dont get why.

Comment: Is this the same issue locally?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with localy but I just develop in Stackbliz so there is not local version. Maybe i just adress my npm import false but I dont know how to do it exactly

Comment: I got it working with "var openrouteservice = require("openrouteservice-js");"

Comment: Oh, updated answer, It's working on my forked stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-adding-openrouteservice-to-angular-application-on-stackbliz

Comment: I will suggest not to mix import and require. check my stackblitz, its working with import